# Python Pandas: Identify data pattern in column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to identify how many different patterns each ID has and what are they in this (simplified) data frame below

```
ID  Items
0   20  A

1   20  A

2   20  B

3   20  B

4   20  B

5   20  B

6   21  A

7   21  B

8   21  A

9   21  B

10  21  C

11  21  C

12  21  C

13  21  C
```

From the data we can see:

ID 20 has a streak of A items and then a streak of B items -> 2 patterns

ID 21 has a streak of (A,B) and then a streak of C -> 2 patterns

My expected result is something like this

20: 2

21: 2

Is there anyway I can do this in pandas?

Comment: Would `AABBAA` be considered 2 patterns or 3?

Comment: it will be 3 patterns

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""ID,Items
0,20,A
1,20,A
2,20,B
3,20,B
4,20,B
5,20,B
6,20,A
7,21,A
8,21,B
9,21,A
10,21,B
11,21,C
12,21,C
13,21,C
14,21,C
15,21,A""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata)

df['streak_group'] = (df['Items'] != df['Items'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Items', 'streak_group']).size().to_frame()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns =['ID', 'Items', 'streak_group',  'streak_size']
df['streak_kind'] = df['Items']+df['streak_size'].apply(str)
df.drop(['streak_group', 'streak_size'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(df)
print(df.groupby('ID')['streak_kind'].value_counts())
print(df['streak_kind'].value_counts())
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
   ID Items streak_kind
0  20     A          A2
1  20     A          A1
2  20     B          B4
3  21     A          A1
6  21     B          B1
8  21     C          C4
ID  streak_kind
20  A1             1
    A2             1
    B4             1
21  A1             1
    B1             1
    C4             1
Name: streak_kind, dtype: int64
A1    2
C4    1
B4    1
A2    1
B1    1
Name: streak_kind, dtype: int64
```